# me2pro - 500 error after install ( magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, http-error-500, m2e

Tried to install the latest version of m2e pro (6.5) which is not, supposedly, available to the public yet but was passed to me by m2e after i inquired about the module.

i followed the install instructions [Link](https://docs.m2epro.com/display/InstallationUpgradeMagento1/Manual+from+archive) spot on using filezilla to upload the contents of the archive to the base magento directory .

After deleting the var/cache and refreshing the admin page i was on i immediately got a 500 error.

I have reached out to m2e and they opened my email 2 days ago (love me some bananatag email tracking) they have yet to responded.

the issue for the log is:

> Warning:
>   include(/home/qr2a1v2skyym/public_html/includes/src/Ess_M2ePro_Model_Cron_Strategy_Observer_KeepAlive.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in
>   /home/qr2a1v2skyym/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on
>   line 94

My boss is freaking out that i am going to have to rebuild the entire install.

I have tried replacing the htaccess with the original, i have do a few other things (and reverted back after it did not help).

Comment: Did you disable the compilation??